SFMC - grouping records from Data Extension into 1 adding values into new fields
I am trying to group the records from Data Extension # 1 ('Self_Insurance_Expiry_Date_Entry_Step1')  into Data Extension # 2
Data Extension # 1  has 2 records with same Contact__c and Self_Insurance_Policy_Expiry_Date__c
These 2 records have different text data type field Id and Registration_Number__c which I need to use in html as a personalised string
My DE # 2 should have 1 records with:
Id and Registration_Number__c field for 1st record
Id_2 and Registration_Number__c_2 for 2nd record
When I am using SQL below, it groups the records into 1, however values for  Id_2 and Registration_Number__c_2 are the same as for  Id and Registration_Number__c:
    SELECT
    a.Contact__c,
    MAX(a.Id) AS Id,
    MAX(a.Registration_Number__c) AS Registration_Number__c,
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.RowNum = 2 THEN b.Id END) AS Id_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.RowNum = 2 THEN b.Registration_Number__c END) AS Registration_Number__c_2,
    MAX(a.Email) AS Email,
    MAX(a.FirstName) AS FirstName,
    MAX(a.LastName) AS LastName,
    MAX(a.Stage__c) AS Stage__c,
    MAX(a.Self_Insurance_Policy_Expiry_Date__c) AS Self_Insurance_Policy_Expiry_Date__c,
    MAX(a.ENTRYDATE) AS ENTRYDATE,
    MAX(a.ENTRY_WEEK_DAY) AS ENTRY_WEEK_DAY
FROM (
    SELECT
        Contact__c,
        Id,
        Registration_Number__c,
        Email,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        Stage__c,
        Self_Insurance_Policy_Expiry_Date__c,
        ENTRYDATE,
        ENTRY_WEEK_DAY,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Contact__c, Self_Insurance_Policy_Expiry_Date__c ORDER BY Id) AS RowNum
    FROM Self_Insurance_Expiry_Date_Entry_Step1
) AS a
LEFT JOIN Self_Insurance_Expiry_Date_Entry_Step1 b
    ON a.Contact__c = b.Contact__c
    AND a.Self_Insurance_Policy_Expiry_Date__c = b.Self_Insurance_Policy_Expiry_Date__c
GROUP BY a.Contact__c, a.Self_Insurance_Policy_Expiry_Date__c

I tried different queries
For example, basic grouping:
    SELECT
    Contact__c,
    MAX(Id) AS Id,
    MAX(Registration_Number__c) AS Registration_Number__c,
    MAX(Id) AS Id__2,
    MAX(Registration_Number__c) AS Registration_Number__c__2,
    MAX(Email) AS Email,
    MAX(FirstName) AS FirstName,
    MAX(LastName) AS LastName,
    MAX(Stage__c) AS Stage__c,
    MAX(Self_Insurance_Policy_Expiry_Date__c) AS Self_Insurance_Policy_Expiry_Date__c,
    MAX(ENTRYDATE) AS ENTRYDATE,
    MAX(ENTRY_WEEK_DAY) AS ENTRY_WEEK_DAY
FROM Self_Insurance_Expiry_Date_Entry_Step1
GROUP BY Contact__c, Self_Insurance_Policy_Expiry_Date__c

All of them were inserting the same values into Id_2 and Registration_Number__c_2 as from  Id and Registration_Number__c
Any ideas why it's happening?
Thanks in advance!

If your DE always has exactly 2 ids/numbers per Contact__c and Date - would not GROUP BY and MIN / MAX be enough?
SELECT
Contact__c
,Self_Insurance_Policy_Expiry_Date__c
,Email
/*, add all other fields of which there is only one */
,MIN(Id) AS Id
,MIN(Registration_Number__c) AS Registration_Number__c
,MAX(Id) AS Id__2
,MAX(Registration_Number__c) AS Registration_Number__c__2
    
FROM Self_Insurance_Expiry_Date_Entry_Step1
GROUP BY Contact__c, Self_Insurance_Policy_Expiry_Date__c, Email 
/* , add all other fields of which there is only one into the GROUP BY */

